# Pairing rows of a dataframe in to a dict using Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am attempting to pair rows of a pandas dataframe (created from an Excel document) in to a dictionary, if I use the following line:

```
[in:] dict = dict(zip(df.loc[1], df.iloc[2]))
[out:] {'Value1': nan, 'Value2': 'Menu', 'Value3': 'Select', nan: nan, nan: nan}
```

I can get the rows of index 1 and 2 in to a dictionary, what I would like the script to do is go through and pair the rows of data like this i.e. a dictionary created from row 1 & 2, 3 & 4, 5 & 6 etc, but no matter what I try I can't get it to do this, any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Please show use a snapshot of your data. Also, please include the efforts you've put in to solve this

Comment: Did I answer your question..?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **small function** I wrote to achieve what you require

```
import pandas as pd

def toDict(df : pd.DataFrame, indices : list):
    DICT = {}
    DATA_SLICE = df.iloc[indices]
    
    for COL in df.columns:
        DICT[COL] = list(DATA_SLICE[COL])

    return DICT
```

This is the data I am working with

```
>>> data
    Motor Screw  Pgain  Vgain     Class
0       E     E      5      4  0.281251
1       B     D      6      5  0.506252
2       D     D      4      3  0.356251
3       B     A      3      2  5.500033
4       D     B      6      5  0.356251
..    ...   ...    ...    ...       ...
162     B     C      3      2  4.499986
163     B     E      3      1  3.699967
164     C     D      4      3  0.956256
165     A     B      3      2  4.499986
166     A     A      6      5  0.806255
```

Let's say I want the data in indices `1`, `3`, `163`, `164` as a `dict`

```
>>> toDict(data, [1, 3, 163, 164])
{'Motor': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'C'], 'Screw': ['D', 'A', 'E', 'D'], 'Pgain': [6, 3, 3, 4], 'Vgain': [5, 2, 1, 3], 'Class': [0.5062525, 5.500033, 3.6999667, 0.9562556999999999]}
```

Or `4` and `162`

```
>>> toDict(data, [4, 162])
{'Motor': ['D', 'B'], 'Screw': ['B', 'C'], 'Pgain': [6, 3], 'Vgain': [5, 2], 'Class': [0.35625148, 4.499986]}
```

Or just `166`

```
>>> toDict(data, [166])
{'Motor': ['A'], 'Screw': ['A'], 'Pgain': [6], 'Vgain': [5], 'Class': [0.8062545999999999]}
```